# Cron expression starting at a fixed time

Tags: cron, scheduler

I can't figure out how to make a cron expression that starts at 11:45 and then runs every 25 minutes every friday between 11:45 and 22:00.

This is the best i could do but i can't make it start at 11:45.

`*/25 11-22 * * 5`

Comment: Did you try 45/25 for the minute?  Should have it start at 11:45, but it will probably only run for the 45 minute of each hour.  It might depend on the system.  I'm trying to figure out something similar.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! but is not what im looking for, the second trigger will come at 12:00 and then at 12:45, I need it to be at 12:10 and then 12:35. please comment if you figure it out on your problem!

Comment: https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html